# How to import zip file in netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, zip, import

when I was trying import a zip file in my netbeans project, I get a error in this line
    `import jericho-html-3.1.src.java.net.htmlparser.jericho.*;`

even though I added the zip file Libraries folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to add library to your project so you could call it in your code. 
From the line `import jericho-html-3.1.src.java.net.htmlparser.jericho.*;` I assume that you try to add source code to the project. This will  not work.

You need to add a library library and not source code. The library file has `.jar` extension. 
When you download a zip file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jerichohtml/files/jericho-html/3.1/ The library is in `/jericho-html-3.1/dist/` folder of the zip.

For library usage take a look on [Sample Programs](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the Projects window right-click on the name of the project that lacks library -> Properties -> The Project Properties window opens. In Categories tree select "Libraries" node -> On the right side of the Project Properties window press button "Add JAR/Folder" -> Select jars you need.

You also can see MockerTim's short Video [How-To](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqhQY7U9Rlc&feature=youtu.be).