# netbeans apache comons lib

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm stuck with importing the apache.common.math3 library to my java project at netbeans v7.3.1. The package "commons-math3-3.2-bin.zip" has been added to the project library folder. Under properties the path of the *.zip has been added to all tabs (compile/processor/run). But when I try to import it in the source code with "import org.apache.commons.math3.*;" it gives an error saying the package "org.appache.. " does not exist. I must be missing some settings but I just cannot find it. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Unzip the bin zip, find the Jars and link the Jars to your project

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import zip file in netbeans project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143921/how-to-import-zip-file-in-netbeans-project)

Answer (score 1):

You need to unzip the ZIP file and include the corresponding JAR file in the Netbeans project.

Refer to this old post for more information:
[How to import zip file in netbeans project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143921/how-to-import-zip-file-in-netbeans-project)